# Matrix Transpose assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have to transpose a matrix in assembly x86-32bit, store the result in another matrix and then print it on screen.
But I do not get the correct result and I can't figure out why. I suppose it is something about indexation.

```
A dd 3,4,1,2,5,6,7,8,9
n dd 9
Tr dd 100 dup(0)
printTr db "transpose of matrix is = ",0
space db " ",0

TRANSPOSE:
    mov edx,nr
    cmp edx,4
    jne DETERMINANT
    mov eax,0
    mov esi,0
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,n
    push ecx
loop_tr1:
    mov eax,A[ebx*4+esi]
    mov Tr[ebx+4*esi],eax
    mov eax,0
    add esi,4
    loop loop_tr1

    pop ecx
    sub ebx,ecx
    push offset printTr
    call printf
    add esp,4
    mov ecx,n
    lea edi,Tr
l4:
    push ecx
    push [edi]
    push offset tip
    call printf
    add esp,8
    push offset space
    call printf
    add esp,4
    mov ebx,Tr
    mov [edi],ebx
    add edi,4
    pop ecx
    loop l4
```

If I enter the matrix above I get the following result: `3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1`.
But I should get: `3 2 7 4 5 8 1 6 9`.

Comment: You never change `ebx`. You only iterate the first column using `esi`. Comment your code especially if you want others to help. Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Please indent loops when writing assembly

Comment: `mov eax,0` in `loop_tr1:` is a possible bug; nothing ever reads that value, you either overwrite EAX again in the next iteration with a load, or you fall through to `printf` which destroys EAX.    `add esi,4` with `4*esi` in the addressing mode seems unlikely; that means you step by 16 bytes = 4 elements in both the src and destination.  Is that intentional?  If so, what's the point of having EBX?  And shouldn't the destination indexing be different from the src indexing?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> A dd 3,4,1,2,5,6,7,8,9
> n dd 9
> ```

An important number is missing here. Your matrix is a square matrix of rank **3**.

```
A dd 3,4,1,2,5,6,7,8,9
n dd 9
r dd 3
```

Your transposing process could use nested loops like in below code.

The `ESI` source index for array *A* takes on these values. They are **offsets** in the array.

```
0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32
```

The `EDI` destination index for array *Tr* takes on these values. They are **indexes** that will get scaled through using `*4`.

```
0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8
```

Every execution of the inner loop spreads out the elements of an entire row of the original matrix. What the outer loop does is moving the starting point that the inner loop will use, one position further.

```
    xor     ebx, ebx
    xor     esi, esi
OuterLoop:
    mov     edi, ebx     ; Set starting point

InnerLoop:
    mov     eax, A[esi]
    mov     Tr[edi*4], eax
    add     esi, 4
    add     edi, r
    cmp     edi, n
    jb      InnerLoop

    inc     ebx          ; Move starting point
    cmp     ebx, r
    jb      OuterLoop
```

For a graphical explanation see the pictures in the answer to [this recent Q/A of mine on codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221312/transposing-a-square-matrix-n-x-n)